# Starting ZIMPL to use on SCIP (0xc000007b)

Tags: scip

I am new to SCIP, have recently downloaded version 3.0.2 on Windows 8. Currently I am trying to input my own problem into the SCIP solver using ZIMPL.

I tried downloading the different versions of ZIMPL on Windows 8. All versions exit automatically when I click on them to run, except zimpl-3.1.0.windows.x86_64.vs10.dbg and zimpl-3.2.0.windows.x86_64.vs10.normal.dbg. These 2 versions displayed an error message about the missing msvcr100d.dll file. After I googled the problem, I downloaded the above mentioned dll file and copied into OS(C:)\ Windows\ System 32. However, another error message related to 0xc000007b was displayed.
"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."
After I clicked OK, "Windows is checking for a solution to the problem..."
Subsequently "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

I followed several tutorials on youtube which did not solve the problem. Will appreciate any help/comments especially from experienced users of ZIMPL and SCIP. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to run Zimpl alone if you want to solve with SCIP anyway. If you download the right SCIP version, Zimpl will be compiled in and you can directly solve *.zpl files from SCIP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the MS Visual C++ Distributable Package:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Also, the tools in the SCIP Optimization Suite do not have a GUI, so you better get comfortable with the shell/console/command line interface. Are you able to run SCIP? A command line window should appear showing the interactive shell.

ZIMPL is not supposed to run on its own. You need to supply it with a problem instance (normally *.zpl) that you would like to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried MS Visual C++ which did not work as well.

Comment: Yup, I managed to follow the tutorial on SCIP website and run the instance stein27. I downloaded the binary version of SCIP which does not come with ZIMPL. Trying to install the Optimization Suite now but I have difficulty following the instructions of compiling SCIP given by http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/INSTALL.php

Comment: You need to be more precise if you want someone to be able to help you with your problems.